# How to pass multiple parameters to the stored proceder in Pl/Sql(Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please help me how to do this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CTCSIS.SP_RptSalesPeriodic_Chathu
(
   intLocIDxx in integer, strFromDate in varchar2, strToDate in varchar2,strSessionId in Varchar2
)
as
Cursor C1 is

 SElECT Distinct
      i.stritmitemnarration                         As FAMILY,
      ctcsis.Fn_GetBrandFamily(intSalSalesSku)      AS MAINFAMILY,
      tab4.strlocnarration                          As LOCATION,
      tab3.intsallocation                           As LOCATION_ID,
      TO_DATE(tab3.strsaleffectdate,'MM/DD/YYYY')   As DATE_RANGE,
      SUM(tab3.dclsalsalestarget)                   AS TARGET,

      ((SELECT SUM(tab1.dclinvdtlqty)
        FROM (select * from ctcsis.tblinvinvoicedetail d where d.intinvdistributerid=301) tab1
        INNER JOIN (select * from ctcsis.tblinvinvoiceheader h where h.intinvdistributerid=301) tab2
        ON tab1.intinvdtlheadcode=tab2.intinvinvoiceid
        WHERE (tab1.intinvdtlsku=tab3.intsalsalessku) AND
          TO_DATE(tab2.strinvinvoicedate,'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE(strFromDate,'MM-DD-YYYY') 
          AND  TO_DATE(strToDate,'MM-DD-YYYY')
          AND tab2.intinvcovloc= tab3.intsallocation))   AS ACTUAL,

     ROUND((((SELECT SUM(tab1.dclinvdtlqty)
      FROM (select * from ctcsis.tblinvinvoicedetail d where d.intinvdistributerid=301) tab1
      INNER JOIN (select * from ctcsis.tblinvinvoiceheader h where h.intinvdistributerid=301) tab2
      ON tab1.intinvdtlheadcode=tab2.intinvinvoiceid
      WHERE (tab1.intinvdtlsku=tab3.intsalsalessku) AND
        TO_DATE(tab2.strinvinvoicedate,'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE(strFromDate,'MM-DD-YYYY') 
        AND TO_DATE(strToDate,'MM-DD-YYYY')
        AND tab2.intinvcovloc= tab3.intsallocation)) - 
          (SUM(tab3.dclsalsalestarget)))*100/ (SUM(tab3.dclsalsalestarget)+ 0.01),2) As "PERC",

      strsessionid  AS SessionNo
    FROM (select * from ctcsis.tblsalsalestarget t where t.intsaldistributerid=301 
         and t.strsalsalesdesc='test'and t.intsalsalesperiod=501 
         and t.intsalsalesday in (12,13)) tab3
      INNER JOIN ctcsis.tblitmitemmaster i
        ON i.intitmid=tab3.intsalsalessku
      INNER JOIN (select * from ctcsis.tblloclocations l where l.intlocdistributerid=301) tab4
        ON tab4.intlocid=tab3.intsallocation

    WHERE
      (i.bititmactive = 1)
      And
      tab3.intsallocation=intLocIDxx //Here I want to pass multiple parameters using IN
```

Comment: It sounds like you want one of the collection types - [associative arrays, nested tables, or VARRAYS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm)

Comment: Can you show me an example

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides several types for passing collections around, such as [associative arrays, nested tables, or VARRAYS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm).

Here's a simple example using a nested table of integers (`t_Ints`), which is what you will need to use as the type for your `intLocIDxx` parameter:

Given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
  ID INT,
  Name VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

Created a nested type for the parameter collection:

```
CREATE TYPE t_Ints IS TABLE OF INT;
```

Then, in the proc, pass the type as an input parameter, and then join to it using the `table()` function. Note that because the nested type is of a simple primitive INT, that the pseudo column `COLUMN_VALUE` is used as the 'value' column name:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetFoos(
  whichInts IN t_Ints,
  results OUT sys_refcursor)
AS BEGIN
  OPEN results FOR 
    SELECT * FROM FOOS f
    INNER JOIN table( whichInts ) wi
    on f.ID = wi.COLUMN_VALUE
END;
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/323d0)

Comment: create or replace procedure p1_pass (p1 varchar2)
is
type t_tab is table of temp_tab%rowtype index by binary_integer; 
v_t_tab t_tab;
begin

execute immediate 'select * from temp_tab where col1 in ( ' || p1 || ' )' bulk collect into v_t_tab;
for i in 1..v_t_tab.count
loop
dbms_output.put_line(v_t_tab(i).col1);
end loop;
end;"Can you explain how to write using in"